# PHP OOP pass variables to sub classes

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I am setting up variable values in a constructor function.
 To keep everything organised, I have created other classes which will only be instantiated once in the "application" class.
I want to pass protected variables value to other classes(frotend, backend ...). I know we can create same variables in these classes & pass variables as arguments. This will lead to a lot of code repetition.
Is there any better way around?
Thanks

```
class application{

    protected $name;
    protected $version;
    protected $slug;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->version = $version;
        $this->slug = $slug;

        $this->includes();
    }

    public function create_settings(){
        //Only one instantiation
        $frontend = new Frontend_Settings();
        $backend = new Backend_Settings;
        //.. more like these
    }

}

class Frontend_Settings{
    public function __construct(){
        print_r($name.$version.$slug);
    }
}

class Backend_Settings{
    public function __construct(){
        print_r($name.$version.$slug);
    }
}



$firstapp = new application( 'First app', '1.0', 'first-app');
$secondapp = new application( 'Second app', '1.0', 'second-app');
```

Comment: Here’s an idea— pass the app instantiation to the frontEnd and backEnd settings: `$frontend = new FrontEnd_Settings($this);`  Then (assuming app has getter functions), frontend has access to all the variables of Application: `class Frontend_Settings { public function __construct($app) { printf(“%s.%s.%s”, $app->name(), $app->version(), $app->slug() ); }}` where name() et al are getters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head...

```
<?php

class application{

    protected $name;
    protected $version;
    protected $slug;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->version = $version;
        $this->slug = $slug;

        // you might want traits instead?
        $this->includes();
    }

    public function create_settings(){
        //Only one instantiation
        $frontend = new Frontend_Settings($this);
        $backend = new Backend_Settings($this);
        //.. more like these
    }

    public function name($name=null) {
      if($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
      }
      return $this->name;
    }

    public function version($version = null) {
      if($version) {
        $this->version = $version;
      }
      return $this->version;
    }

    public function slug($slug = null) {
      if($slug) {
        $this->slug = $slug;
      }
      return $this->slug;
    }

}

class Frontend_Settings{
    public function __construct($app){
        $this->app = $app;
        printf(
          "%s.%s.%s",
          $app->name(),
          $app->version(),
          $app->slug()
        );
    }
}

class Backend_Settings{
    public function __construct($app){
        $this->app = $app;
        printf(
          "%s.%s.%s",
          $app->name(),
          $app->version(),
          $app->slug()
        );
    }
}



$firstapp = new application( 'First app', '1.0', 'first-app');
$secondapp = new application( 'Second app', '1.0', 'second-app');
```

Be aware, though, that if Frontend or Backend makes any changes to $app, that change will be passed by reference: i.e., if you change it in front end, it's changed in back end.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for.